# Using ui:include as recursiv

Tags: jsf

I would like to save time and want to integrate an existing JSF page several times inside the same page, but with other parameters / objects...

My setup is like this:

**JSF page: reportPageSectionEditMode.jsf**

```
<ui:repeat value="#{currentPageSection.contentComponentList}"
        var="contentComponent" varStatus="myVarStatusContentComponent">

        <ui:include
            src="/portal/reporting/edit/designMode/componentDesignModeView.xhtml">
            
            
            <ui:param name="currentContentComponent" value="#{contentComponent}" />
            <ui:param name="currentPageSection" value="#{currentPageSection}" />
            <ui:param name="currentContentComponent"
                value="#{myVarStatusContentComponent.index}" />
            <ui:param name="pageName" value="pageBody" />
            
        </ui:include>

    </ui:repeat>
```

**Page: componentDesignModeView.jsf**

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block"
    rendered="#{contentComponent.component.componentType == 'TABLE'}">

    <ui:include
        src="/portal/reporting/edit/components/table/tableEditMode.xhtml">

        <ui:param name="component" value="#{contentComponent.component}" />
        <ui:param name="currentPageSection" value="#{currentPageSection}" />
    </ui:include>

</h:panelGroup>
```

**Page: tableEditMode.jsf**

```
<h:panelGroup>
        <table class="selectableComponentChild">
            <tbody>
                <ui:repeat value="#{contentComponent.component.tableRowList}"
                    var="tableRow" varStatus="myVarStatusBody">
                    <tr>
                        <ui:repeat value="#{tableRow.tableCellList}" var="tableCell"
                            varStatus="myVarTableCell">

                                <ui:repeat value="#{tableCell.contentComponentList}"
                                    rendered="#{tableCell.contentComponentList != null}"
                                    var="contentComponentInCell">

                                    <c:if
                                        test="#{contentComponent ne contentComponentInCell}">

                                        <ui:include
                                            src="/portal/reporting/edit/designMode/componentDesignModeView.xhtml">

                                            <ui:param name="contentComponent"
                                                value="#{contentComponentInCell}" />

                                        </ui:include>

                                    </c:if>

                                </ui:repeat>
                            </th>
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </tr>
                </ui:repeat>
            </tbody>

        </table>
</h:panelGroup>
```

In **tableEditMode.jsf** I want to include again the **componentDesignModeView.jsf**.
I´ve tried many thing like rendered, c:if c:when, but nothing was working.
If I haven´t add any c:if I got a **Stackoverflow Exception**.

Any idea how I can solve that?

I´ve tried also with Omnifaces:

```
<o:tree value="#{tableCell.contentComponentList}"
                                    var="contentComponentInCell"
                                    rendered="#{tableCell.contentComponentList != null}">

                                    <o:treeNode>
                                        <ul>
                                            <o:treeNodeItem>
                                                <li><ui:include
                                                        src="/portal/reporting/edit/designMode/componentDesignModeView.xhtml">

                                                        <ui:param name="contentComponent"
                                                            value="#{contentComponentInCell}" />

                                                    </ui:include> <o:treeInsertChildren /></li>
                                            </o:treeNodeItem>
                                        </ul>
                                    </o:treeNode>

                                </o:tree>

enter code here
```

Comment: But where can I find the ui:include?

Comment: Thanks, but how should this look like? I´ve updated my question with the Omnifaces code...